# How can I avoid calling System.load twice?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a class that calls a native function to get information about a system from its CMOS.  The class has a static initialization block which loads the library containing the native function, and it looks something like this:

```
package lib.sysid;

public class SysId
{
    private static native int getSysIdNative();
    private static final String SYS_ID_PATH = "libsysid.so";

    static
    {
        System.load(SYS_ID_PATH);
    }

    public static int getSysIdFromCMOS()
    {
        int returnValue = getSysIdNative();
    }
}
```

According to my testing, the method works fine the first time I use it, but if I call the method again at a later time, the static initialization block also runs, causing an UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library libsysid.so already loaded in another classloader
```

How can I avoid the static initialization block from executing the `System.load()` method if it has already been run?

Alternatively, is there a way for me to attempt to "unload" the library if it is already loaded before calling the `System.load()` method again?

EDIT: Strangely enough, if I surround the `System.load()` call with a try-catch block, I still get an UnsatisfiedLinkError, but this time it comes from the actual call to `getSysIdNative()`.  The error I see is the following:

```
lib.sysid.SysId.getSysIdNative()I
```

What the heck is that "I" that shows up? I've tried to attach a debugger to this code to see where the message gets populated, but so far I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but I think the only way for a single JVM to load a class (and execute its static initializers) twice is to load it with different classloaders. So there may be a second classloader involved here that you're not aware of. This would apply if a different (set of) classloader(s) is in effect the second time around.

Under a "real" operating system, `java -verbose:class` would give you loader messages to verify this with. I'm not sure how you'd go about verifying this on an embedded system. You could modify `getSysId()` to print (?) or somehow dump a reference to `SysId.class.getClassLoader()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Carl is right.  The only way that a static initializer can run twice in a JVM is if the class is being loaded in multiple class loaders.

> `lib.sysid.SysId.getSysIdNative()I`  What the heck is that "I" that shows up?

That's easy.  The `I` is based on the internal representation of types in signatures that is defined by the class file format.  In particular, `I` means the primitive `int` type; see [Class.getName()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()), etc.  This matches your method's return type.

(It is a little bit confusing that these primitive type names show up in application space occasionally, but they do.  Another case where you can see them is when you call `toString()` on a class that inherits the method implementation from the `Object` class.)

Comment: That's exactly the problem I see. There is some logic in the system I am using that "reloads" all of the library files associated with the system, including my above file, but it does this through a different class loader than the one that first loads the files.