# Apache Pig running JNI on hadoop can't load shared object on multiple maps (but runs fine on just one map)

Tags: java, hadoop, java-native-interface, apache-pig

So we've wrote a JNI, then we wrote a UDF to be able to call our JNI from Apache Pig.
Now the problem is that we get this error, but only when we run it with multiple maps (With just one map it all works fine):

```
Native code library failed to load. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
Can't load library: /usr/lib/libdclassjni.so
```

I think this is related to the [following piece in Apache Pig's manual :](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/udf.html#Function+Instantiation)

> One problem that users run into is when they make assumption about how
>   many times a constructor for their UDF is called. For instance, they
>   might be creating side files in the store function and doing it in the
>   constructor seems like a good idea. The problem with this approach is
>   that in most cases Pig instantiates functions on the client side to,
>   for instance, examine the schema of the data.
>
> Users should not make assumptions about how many times a function is
>   instantiated; instead, they should make their code resilient to
>   multiple instantiations. For instance, they could check if the files
>   exist before creating them.

Inside the UDF we have a constructor which in turn instantiates another class and that one does

```
System.load("/usr/lib/libdclassjni.so").
```

I can assure that we have lidbclassjni.so installed on all nodes. So the main question would be why Apache Pig isn't able to load the shared object. And also, how should a UDF look so that we avoid this problem.

**TL;DR =>**

Using a JNI inside an Apahce Pig UDF on hadoop. Works fine on one map, but on multiple maps I get

> Native code library failed to load. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   Can't load library: /usr/lib/libdclassjni.so

Thank you for any insight on this

UPDATE:

FIXED

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the JVM is attempting to load the library twice?

Comment: @StephenC thank you ! This possibility escaped me. How can I prevent that ?

Comment: @StephenC I'm not sure if loading twice is the problem. The error for loading twice is [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338531/how-can-i-avoid-calling-system-load-twice). If that was the case it should say `"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library libdclassjni.so already loaded in another classloader"`  , but my error is different.

Answer (score 2):

[FIXED] Turned out the .so was not present on all the hadoop nodes.